# blue green water after softener installation

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

I recently installed a water softener.  We have SUPER hard water and it's now within a normal range.

When the softener recharges the water is super fizzy and has a light blue/green tint.

After a few hours the color change and fizziness goes away.

Is my water too soft? Could it be damaging the pipes or just clean out all the old crap that's been in the pipes for the last 20+ years?

Comment: Do you have the recharge period set to overnight when the water is not subject to consumption?

Comment: Right how it's just set to recharge when needed.

Comment: You unit may be more "intelligent" than the antique we have. Our tech said use the water at a minimum between 1am and 3am, not too hard to manage. Check your manual to see if you have similar recommendations.